# Checking XML Document befor upload to server via php

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I am creating a script to upload XML-files to a server, where you enter how often specific tags occur in the file. Now I wanted to automate this, so that i check the XML-file befor uploading, so that the previous manually entered fields are filled automaticly.

I just dont get the point how i can get the content of the file befor actually uploading it - i want to use Javascript for the check and auto-fillment.

The upload is completly realized in php.

Someone have an idea for me?

Edit:

```
var fileInput;

window.onload = function() {
    fileInput = document.getElementById('file_input');
};

function getNodes() {
    var anzNodes = fileInput.getElementsByTagName("node").length;
    return anzNodes;
}

function getEdges() {
    var anzEdges = fileInput.getElementsByTagName("edge").length;
    return anzEdges;
}

function fillForm() {
    document.getElementById("nodes").value = getNodes();
    document.getElementById("edges").value = getEdges();
}
```

So I have a html-form with the ID file_input. I try to grab that file (which is XML) befor uploading, search it for the amount of "node" and "edge" tags, and autofill these information into the html form. This should happen when the file is chosen. Is this better?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. But, if you want to autocomplete certain data in your javascript fields. You need to store the same data initially in the DB or as a cookie. 

2nd time, when you try upload, just , pick up the same data, based on some criteria and load them.

Comment: Question is far too broad. Provide examples along with more concise explanation of objective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and will provide it for completeness.

My Javascript part:

```
var openFile = function (event) {
    var input = event.target;
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function () {
        var anzEdges = (reader.result.match(/<edge/g) || []).length;
        var anzNodes = (reader.result.match(/<node/g) || []).length;
        document.getElementById("nodes").value = anzNodes;
        document.getElementById("edges").value = anzEdges;
    };
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};
```

and the relevant html-code:

```
<input type="file" onchange="openFile(event)" name="file_upload" size="60"><br>
<input type="number" id="nodes" name="nodes" min="2" readonly><br>
<input type="number" id="edges" name="edges" min="1" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) functionality in JavaScript to grab the document before uploading it. Then you can read the text of the file and pre-process it before sending it to the server.